# Sliding Windows Starting Point

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to calculate some sliding average for a bounded dataset, which have dates attached to it as well as some value.

Based on the docs from:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/SlidingWindows
and
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing#sliding-time-windows

First I am emitting the datestamp with `outputWithTimestamp`, dividing the timestamps into:

```java
Window.into(
    SlidingWindows
        .of(Duration.standardDays(3))
        .every(Duration.standardDays(1)))
```

So for a PCollection of dataset:

```java
[Jan 3rd, 100]
[Jan 4th, 200]
[Jan 5th, 400]
```

The output PCollection I am seeing is `[100, 300, 700, 600, 400]`, which seems to imply the windowing function starts with a window of Jan 1st - 3rd, and ends with a window of Jan 5th - Jan 7th. Does that make sense that the first window seems to start before my PCollection?

Comment: I read the unit tests for these timestamps: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/SlidingWindowsTest.java

The part that I missed was that the first window doesn't in fact start at the first element of the collection, but the first non-empty window that includes an element (in this case Jan 1st - 3rd)... unfortunately this means that my averages will be throw off since I don't really want to calculate Jan 1st - 3rd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to indicate the window associated with each element in your output PCollection, you would see this:

```
[Jan 1-3, 100]
[Jan 2-4, 300]
[Jan 3-5, 700]
[Jan 4-6, 600]
[Jan 5-7, 400]
```

Event time is "platonic" in the sense that it all exists "all at once". If you have a dataset where you know the data is complete only for a particular interval, you can filter these results to remove the values that do not fall within the interval with good data.

Comment: Hi Kenn, thanks for the reply.

Does that mean that it is correct to use sliding windows to 'partition' the data, but then do another round of filtering to narrow down the windows? for example, in this case the only interval I care about would be Jan 3-5.

Comment: @iggybbz, if you are only concerned with events occurring on Jan 3-5, I believe it would be best to apply a Filter to the PCollection, prior to Windowing.

Comment: @AndrewMo my comment was a bit confusing, I meant Jan 3-5 just for this example. 

My actual code already does a filter to the PCollection to narrow down the dates (throw away everything before the 3rd), it's just that calculating a rolling window minimum average is thrown off since I'm seeing incomplete windows. I thought about using a trigger with counting the elements but there's no guarantee on how sparse my data is.

Comment: I think this ended up working, I was doing another filter on the output PCollection to remove windows that were 'incomplete', thanks!